# How to get all php array index from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file where I saved all language string. This is the content:

```
function lang($phrase)
{
    static $lang = array(
        'step_one' => 'First step',
        'step_two' => 'Second step',
         ... and so on ...
    );
    return $lang[$phrase];
}
```

Essentially, when I load a javascript file I want store all array index in a variable like this:

```
var Lang = <?php echo json_encode(lang()); ?>;
```

this code line is inserted in a script, this script is available in a php file. Now before of execute this line I have imported the php file where all string translation is available. What I'm trying to achieve, is get all index of this array, in the variable `Lang`. 
Actually I can load a single string traduction from php like this:

```
lang('step_one');
```

but how I can save this array in javascript variable?

Comment: You can use `array_keys` on the array if you just want all keys. http://php.net/array_keys

Comment: like `<?php echo json_encode(lang(array_keys)); ?>;` ?

Comment: Your function needs to return the *whole* array, then you can use `array_keys`. `echo json_encode(array_keys(lang());` You can check if `$phrase` is empty in your function and if so return the whole array (you should check the variable anyway to not raise any warnings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) to retrieve all array keys. To do that you need your function to return the whole array on request. You can do that with leaving the argument (`$phrase`) empty and do an if condition with [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) in your `lang` function. You also need to set a default value for `$phrase` in your function to not raise any errors if you don't pass an argument to the function.

```
echo json_encode(array_keys(lang());
```

And the function:

```
function lang($phrase = "")
{
    static $lang = array(
        'step_one' => 'First step',
        'step_two' => 'Second step',
         ... and so on ...
    );

    if(empty($phrase)) {
        return $lang;
    } else {
        if(isset($lang[$phrase])) { //isset to make sure the requested string exists in the array, if it doesn't - return empty string (you can return anything else if you want
            return $lang[$phrase];
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

I also added [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to make sure the requested element exists in your language array. This will prevent raising warnings.

Comment: @kingkero Oh, clickable links in code tags - nice to have - but nothing important.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yes, but still better (in my opinion) than an addendum of links